# how to solve 'datetime.datetime' object is not iterable' TypeError

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a piece of code iterating though a number of files in an AWS S3 folder. I want to collect the last modified datetimestamps for all objects and be able to sort them in ascending or descending order.
my code looks like this:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket('myS3bucket')

for my_bucket_object in my_bucket.objects.all():
    if my_bucket_object.key.startswith('inbox/'):
        changedate_dt = my_bucket_object.last_modified
        changedate_str = sorted(changedate_dt, reverse=False)
        print(changedate_str)
```

I am getting the error:

> TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not iterable

how can I solve this?

Comment: You can't sort a `datetime` object. What exactly are you trying to accomplish with the `sorted(changedate_dt, reverse=False)` statement? Going by your variable names, I'm gathering that you want a `str` representation of the `datetime` variable? Do you want the `str` to be sorted?

Comment: Hi, I don't necessarly need a str representation of my datetime. As long as I can sort them on its fine in time-order asc or desc. I'm just trying stuff and thought this could work.

Comment: Sort what though? You have a single `datetime` object. You can sort a collection of such objects, but not an individual instance. Are you trying to sort all the `datetime`s that would be extracted from `my_bucket.objects.all()`?

Comment: @mypetlion yes I'm trying to sort all datetimes from the loop. so, deriving from your remark, I should first stuff the datetimes from the loop in a collection? how should I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be making a list of your  `datetime.datetime` values, rather than simply trying to sort each individual `datetime.datetime`:

```
changedate_list = []

for my_bucket_object in my_bucket.objects.all():
    if my_bucket_object.key.startswith('inbox/'):
        changedate_list.append(my_bucket_object.last_modified)
```

You can then sort the list of datetimes and print it out (in isoformat if you like):

```
changedate_list.sort()
for changedate in changedate_list:
    print changedate.isoformat()
```

Comment: perfect!. with print changedate.isoformat() changed to print(changedate.isoformat()) this works like a charm. Thanks!